# Cannot Use InterceptorRegistry While the Application Extend Neo4jConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, neo4j

I am using spring boot application mvc with graphDb (Neo4j) as my database.
And I have problem when I have to do internationalization for my app.
I have this code on my application.java

```
public class Application extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    GraphDatabase graphDatabase;

    @Bean
    GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("my-graphdb");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I tried to implement internationalization, the tutor says that I need to implement:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

This code above need the class is extended by WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.
This is the problem, I didn't use WebMvcConfigurerAdapter so I cannot add the method above.
Do I have another option to make my internationalization work well with Neo4jConfiguration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out how to make it work.
I just have to add new file that extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and put the addInterceptors module into that new file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Which tutorial are you referring to?
2. you can also create your own `Neo4jConfiguration` subclass and `@Import` it onto your boot application context